# Problem in reading/writing bytes with atmega16 & 24LC256 EEPROM

Tags: atmega

I am beginner in MCU world.
I have learned quite few things and felt quite good.
I am trying to experiment with my Atmega16 and 24LC256 eeprom chip.
After making all the necessary connections on breadboard I uploaded my program to atmega16.
My problem is that after when I am reading back my data after writing it to the flash it is always returning 0xFF.
I am unable to figure out what's going wrong here.
Please help me find out the problem.
Here is my code:

```
#ifndef F_CPU                    // if F_CPU was not defined in Project -> Properties
#define F_CPU 2000000UL            // define it now as 2 MHz unsigned long
#endif
#include <avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
#include "util/delay.h"
#define EEPROM_WRITE 0xA0
#define EEPROM_READ 0xA1
void i2c_init()
{
    //set SCL to 100kHz
    // CPU freq = 2MHz
    TWSR = 0x00;
    TWBR = (1<<TWPS1);
    //enable TWI
    TWCR = (1<<TWEN);
}
void i2c_start()
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
}
void i2c_stop()
{
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(1<<TWEN);
    _delay_ms(100);
}
void i2c_write(uint8_t u8data)
{
    TWDR = u8data;
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
    _delay_ms(10);
}
//read byte with NACK
uint8_t i2c_read()
{
    //TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN);
    //while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
    //return TWDR;

    TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWEA);
    while ((TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) == 0);
    return TWDR;
}
int main()
{
    i2c_init();
    uint8_t readByte=0;
    uint16_t address=0x0;
    uint8_t writeVal=0;
    while (1)
    {
        for (int a =0;a<128;a++)
        {
            i2c_start();
            i2c_write(EEPROM_WRITE);
            i2c_write(address>>8);
            i2c_write(address & 0xFF);
            i2c_write(writeVal);
            i2c_stop();
            writeVal++;
            address++;
        }

        address=0;
        for (int a =0;a<128;a++)
        {
            i2c_start();
            i2c_write(EEPROM_READ);
            i2c_write(address>>8);
            i2c_write(address & 0xFF);
            readByte =i2c_read();
            _delay_ms(10);
            i2c_stop();
            address++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with the easiest:  Confirm the Address pins and the WP pin are all tied to ground on the breadboard (and not floating).  It's also a good idea to check for ACK's after a write sequence (to confirm your writes are being acknowledged, like after the control byte, address word, and data byte).  Power-up an oscilloscope and monitor the i2c lines to make sure the activity you see is what you expect.  _delays sprinkled around are always a red flag.  They shouldn't be necessary...  (Re-)Read section 7.0 of the datasheet to avoid them.

Comment: As an aside: page writes and sequential reads would be much more efficient.  Page writes (Section 6.2), would also extend the life of the flash.